# Kubernetes - Ingress with gRPC

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, grpc, kubernetes-ingress, grpc-java

I have a very simple grpc-server. When I expose them directly via NodePort everything works just fine. I do not have any issues with this.

```
grpc-client --> NodePort --> grpc-server
```

I changed the `NodePort` service to `ClusterIP` service and tried to use `ingress controller` to route the traffic to the grpc-server. The set up is like this. ingress and grpc-server are part of k8s cluster. grpc-client is outside - which is my local machine.

```
grpc-client --> ingress --> clusterip --> grpc-server
```

My ingress is like this.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: web-ingress
  namespace: test
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "GRPC"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      proxy_set_header l5d-dst-override $service_name.$namespace.svc.cluster.local:$service_port;
      grpc_set_header l5d-dst-override $service_name.$namespace.svc.cluster.local:$service_port;    
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
         serviceName: grpc-server
         servicePort: 6565
```

Whenever I send a request, I get en exception like this in the client side.

```
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL: HTTP/2 error code: FRAME_SIZE_ERROR
Received Rst Stream
```

Ingress log is like this

```
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jul/2020:03:52:38 +0000] "PRI * HTTP/2.0" 400 157 "-" "-" 0 0.001 [] [] - - - - c9d46af55aa8a2b450f9f72e9d550023
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jul/2020:03:52:38 +0000] "PRI * HTTP/2.0" 400 157 "-" "-" 0 0.000 [] [] - - - - a9e0f02851473467fc553f2a4645377d
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jul/2020:03:52:40 +0000] "PRI * HTTP/2.0" 400 157 "-" "-" 0 0.001 [] [] - - - - fcc0668f300bd5e7e12325ae7c26fa9d
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jul/2020:03:52:41 +0000] "PRI * HTTP/2.0" 400 157 "-" "-" 0 0.001 [] [] - - - - dea2b8eb8f6884ac512654af3c2e6b47
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jul/2020:03:52:43 +0000] "PRI * HTTP/2.0" 400 157 "-" "-" 0 0.001 [] [] - - - - 0357acafce928ee05aaef1334eed1b69
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jul/2020:03:52:44 +0000] "PRI * HTTP/2.0" 400 157 "-" "-" 0 0.001 [] [] - - - - df9b75d79d9177e39a901dfa020912f2
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jul/2020:03:52:44 +0000] "PRI * HTTP/2.0" 400 157 "-" "-" 0 0.000 [] [] - - - - bb27acd5b86fd057af1ca8fe93f7d857
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jul/2020:03:52:44 +0000] "PRI * HTTP/2.0" 400 157 "-" "-" 0 0.001 [] [] - - - - 2ced9207652fc564bb94e0d4a14ae6fc
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jul/2020:03:52:45 +0000] "PRI * HTTP/2.0" 400 157 "-" "-" 0 0.001 [] [] - - - - b99fab13df2f64a6a0a901237dadfa27
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jul/2020:03:52:45 +0000] "PRI * HTTP/2.0" 400 157 "-" "-" 0 0.002 [] [] - - - - 40cb75f4e4b3df28be66044a0825f1c6
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jul/2020:03:52:46 +0000] "PRI * HTTP/2.0" 400 157 "-" "-" 0 0.001 [] [] - - - - 89cac6709278b4e54b0349075500bf74
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jul/2020:03:52:46 +0000] "PRI * HTTP/2.0" 400 157 "-" "-" 0 0.000 [] [] - - - - 0b032199a053069df185c620de497c90
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jul/2020:03:52:46 +0000] "PRI * HTTP/2.0" 400 157 "-" "-" 0 0.001 [] [] - - - - 5a07b1e24ea3e8e2066a7ed8950f7040
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jul/2020:03:53:46 +0000] "PRI * HTTP/2.0" 400 157 "-" "-" 0 0.000 [] [] - - - - 0f63eec0d0ccb9cc87c2fbb1fdfae48f
```

Looks like the grpc-server never received any request as I do not see any log there.

What is going on?

Comment: Which version of the controller you're using?  Can you try to decrease `SETTINGS_MAX_FRAME_SIZE` on client side and check if you till have this error?

Comment: Also, do you have tls on your backend server?

Comment: I didn't experience the same error as you but I thought this may be helpful. It provides an example for using an NGINX Ingress Controller to expose a gRPC service in the cluster. It does SSL termination at the ingress controller as well: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/docs/examples/grpc

Answer (score 4):

That error you encountered comes from the default configuration of the nginx ingress controller (this is taken from the [ingress github config](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/ca74f9ad7d9a9072071dc94bfb8b5eb64f1e1fb0/internal/ingress/controller/config/config.go#L406)):

```
// Enables or disables the HTTP/2 support in secure connections
// http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_v2_module.html
// Default: true
UseHTTP2 bool `json:"use-http2,omitempty"`
```

This can be also verified by checking your ingress controller settings :

```
kubectl exec -it -n <name_space> <nginx_ingress_controller_pod> -- cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf 

## start server _
   server {
          server_name _ ;

          listen 80 default_server reuseport backlog=511 ;
          listen 443 default_server reuseport backlog=511 ssl http2 ;
```

You're trying to connect through port 80 for which there is no `http2` support in default configuration. GRCP works only with `http2` so you should try to make a request using port 443.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: This fixed the issue for me! After adding a cert to the ingress controller, sending traffic to port 443 works. But using a cert for local development is not ideal. I couldn't find any way to reconfigure this via ingress-nginx [annotations](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/) or [configmaps](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/), so I think it would require a complete [custom template](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/custom-template/)?

Comment: @Stabby how's it possible it fixed the issue by just adding a certificate? I did it and used your same ingress template and I still get the http2 frame too large error. What else did you change to make it work with GRPC on port 443?